# Error: 'Non-constructor pattern not allowed in sequential mode' (Isabelle)

Tags: function, sum, syntax-error, isabelle

I am trying to define a function `Sum f k` that sums `f` from 0 up to k-1 such that

```
Sum f k = f 0 + ⋯ + f (k - 1).
```

I have defined it as follows:

```
fun Sum :: "(nat => nat) => nat => nat" where
  "Sum f 1 = f 0"
| "Sum f k = f (k-1) + Sum f (k-1)"
```

However, this gives the following error message:

```
Malformed definition:
Non-constructor pattern not allowed in sequential mode.
⋀f. Sum f 1 = f 0
```

This error message disappears when I define `Sum f 0 = f 0`, but this is not the function I am trying to define. I can also use `function` and give a soundness proof myself, but I would be quite surprised if that was necessary

Could someone explain the error message and recommend a workaround/correction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use constructors in pattern matches. The constructors of `nat` are `0` and `Suc`. So if you write `1` as `(Suc 0)` it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your advice, but it now has 'unfinished subgoals'. I expect that means I need to use `function` instead - although I would prefer not to have to.

Comment: Okay, I tried `fun Sum :: "(nat => nat) => nat => nat" where
  "Sum f 0 = 0"
| "Sum f (Suc k) = f k + Sum f k"` and that seemed to work! I guess it needs to be `Suc` everywhere (and now the 'base case' makes more sense).

Comment: You got unfinished subgoals, because your original definition did not terminate: `Sum f 0 = f (0-1) + Sum f (0-1) = f 0 + Sum f 0 = ...`. Adding the case for 0 fixed this.